# convert an object to a JSON styled string for mariadb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mariadb

i need to convert a node object to a string, but i need to convert the colon characters into commas for mariadb JSON usage.

so for example something like this:

```
{ 'one' : 'this is for ONE', 'two': "this is for 'TWO'" }
```

will become this:

```
'one' , 'this is for ONE', 'two', 'this is for \'TWO\''
```

currently i am doing this:

```
JSON.stringify(newValue).slice(1, -1).replace(/":"/g,'","');
```

(slice to remove the {} characters)

it has been recommended to me to use Object entries().map().join() instead to avoid conflicts if the JSON values contain colons.

this is the best i have been able to come up with:

```
Object.keys(tester)
    .map( (key) => { return "'" + key + "','" + tester[key].replace(/'/g, "\\'") + "'"; })
    .join(",");
```

and yes i am partial to "one line" answers if possible.

any suggestions?  or is there a simple node plugin to do this?   i looked at babel but it didn't look like a conventional simple plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You would be best of with letting the driver or the DB handle the escaping by using parameterized/prepared statements:

```
const query = Object.keys(tester).map(() => '?').join(',')
const values = Object.keys(tester).reduce((prev, curr) => prev.concat([curr, tester[curr]]), [])
```

But doesn't mariadb have support for JSON? The mysql node driver can insert an object directly into the database